# How to display favicons in chrome <HTML>

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, meta-tags, favicon

I had a problem with displaying my favicon in Chrome. It works fine in FireFox, but I can't get it to display in Chrome. Also, something else I would like to ask is if you have to actually have a website on the web to display favicons because I took the link to the favicon from this website and tried it on my html code and it worked just fine. Something else to note is that the file is up a directory, so I don't want people to correct me on the ../ that appears in the code. Like I said, it works in FireFox. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../GRAFX/ICO/fav.ico">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to have the website on the web to view favicons in Chrome. It happens because Chrome old versions do not support favicon hosted on your computer. The favicon has to be hosted on an internet server. Use a photo hosting website. I recommend ImageShack.

After, just do this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.urloftheimage.com/image.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Major browsers support PNG, JPG and GIF as extensions of the favicon. It doesn't has to be .ico, but it's good to use it.

Comment: in type you should have had type="image/png"

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following lines to your head tag. That will supports the major browsers.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://www.example.com/image.gif">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico">
```

PS: don't forget to delete the browsers cache before you try the code!

Comment: So I guess you have to have the website on the web to view favicons in Chrome?